# Throwing exception from okhttp3 Intercepter crashing when using suspended functions in retrofit service

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

1. List item

I am making a simple network call where I thrown an exception from an Interceptor when network is not available to show appropriate message to the user.
When I model the call as a suspended function and emit the data in ViewModel, I am getting a crash in the app without a stack trace for the issue:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.x.x.x.debug, PID: 14247
```

**Definition causing crash:**

Service

```
interface Service {
    @GET("v1/count")
    suspend fun getCounts(): Response<Counts>
}
```

Repository:

```
suspend fun getCounts(): Response<Counts> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { service.getCounts() }
}
```

ViewModel

```
fun getCounts(): LiveData<Response<Counts>> = liveData { emit(repository.getCounts()) }
```

Observer in Fragment:

```
viewModel.getCounts().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                ...
            }
        })
```

---

**Definition working fine:**

```
interface Service {
    @GET("v1/count")
    fun getCounts(): Call<FeesCounts>
}
```

Note: The crash doesn't come in both cases above if there is no exception thrown in the Interceptor.

Any thoughts on what could be the root cause of such a behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Modify it like this :

```
data class Hello (
    val count: Long = 0
)
```

Keep the "count" same as JSON response.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. But, apparently the issue is with using suspended functions and throwing exception from interceptor. I have edited my original question.